# Is there a way to use the Microsoft.Identity.Web for an external login button, without relying on Microsoft authentication?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory

We have a SAAS application, for which we want to add an option to login with Microsoft. We can run the samples perfectly fine, but those samples use Microsoft's `[Authorize]` attributes to mark pages to automatically require login for.

We have our own authentication and permissions system.

All we want is a button "Login with Microsoft", to initiate the OAuth process, and end up with a fully validated and trusted email address, and continue with our own mechanism from there.
I cannot seem to find any way to do that with Microsoft's code - which handles a lot of situations, but all of them are fully automated.

It's not a lot of code to write to redirect to OAuth and receive the `id_token` on the other end, but still if we can take advantage of MS' system and perhaps support more authorities in the future with a plug-and-play manner - that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple:

### Option 1

Microsoft fails to properly document this in the right places, but it is in a sample that shows up in the main `aspnetcore` repo.

It's right here: [Microsoft Sample](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/samples/SocialSample/Startup.cs)

And the gist is that we can configure the authentication schemes you want like the many samples out there, and then just return a `ChallengeResult` or call `this.Challenge(MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` from the page and return the result.

We can also add events for the authentication lifecycle, like when the authentication completed - to act on it and hook it up to our own authentication system. We do that on each `.Add[Whatever]` call for a authentication service.

### Option 2 - a bit more manual

- Generating the authorization urls is simple (and redirect)
- Then we get the JWT (id_token) back
- Use `OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever` from `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` to retrive the set of keys from the `OIDC` endpoint (`[authority]/.well-known/openid-configuration`)
- Use the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` from `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` to read the token, and run the validations with the fetched signatures.

There's no need to use any JWT library, not to validate the timestamps manually, or the signatures.